# Deciphering output from R2WinBUGS

Tags: r, bugs

I have been struggling to figure out how to identify which output the parameter came from. For e.g. in the following code I run the model for 2 iterations. At the end of it I obtain 2 outputs named `bugs.output[[1]], bugs.output[[2]]`. Now when I type `mean (p[,2])` it gives me the mean for `p[2]` from the second output. How do I specify that I need the mean for `p[2]` for the `1st` or the `ith` output?

Here is how my output looks:

```
         mean       sd      2.5%       25%       50%       75%     97.5%
alpha      4.20338  1.14447   2.44975   3.39950   4.01550   4.82925   7.05405
p[1]       0.16691  0.04036   0.09974   0.13720   0.16445   0.19222   0.25308
p[2]       0.14286  0.03812   0.07665   0.11670   0.14020   0.16702   0.22630
p[3]       0.21238  0.04240   0.13740   0.18295   0.21050   0.23845   0.30360.......
```

And here is my code:

```
library("R2WinBUGS")
trial.data <- read.table("simuldatBB_6_30.csv", header=T)
p_true<- read.table("p_BB_6_30.csv",header=F)
bugs.output <- list()
for(i in 1:2){
       nausea <- as.integer(trial.data[i,])
       bugs.output[[i]] <- bugs(
       data=list(nausea=nausea, N=63),
       inits=list(
               list(theta=.300,mu=3),
               list(theta=.350, mu=3)
               ),
       model.file="conj_nausea_script_2.txt",
       parameters.to.save = c("alpha","p"),
n.chains=2, n.iter=12000, n.burnin=5000,
bugs.directory="E://AChaudhuri/winbugs14/WinBUGS14",
working.directory=NULL)
attach.bugs(bugs.output[[i]],overwrite=NA)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You complicated it a lot by calling `bugs` this way and using `attach` in a for loop! That's a big unclean thing. It's really hard to say what the result is. Attach should be used with care even in normal case, not even say in a for-loop.
No wonder you got lost. Don't use attach this way!

Comment: I completely agree; attach is dangerous, and best avoided.

Comment: without using attach if I type mean (p[,2]) it gives me the error Error in mean(p[, 2]) : object 'p' not found. How else can I read the output and do some analysis?

Comment: @anamika, you have to go directly to the structure: look at `bugs.output[[i]]$mean$p`. For more how to access the values see  http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2WinBUGS/vignettes/R2WinBUGS.pdf

Comment: Thanks Tomas, This has been really helpful. I am new to this forum and I am pleased at how helpful everybody has been. I have seen this article earlier. I am actually trying to read in the quantiles. In normal case the 2.5% would be read as quantile(p[i],c(.025)) but in this case that doesnt seem to work. I dont see any reference on the article

Comment: @anamika, for quantiles use `quantile` function on `bugs.output[[i]]$sims.list` (this is the posterior distribution) or something like that... or try to look into the bugs.output structure if there are the quantiles already computed.

Comment: @Tomas: I had seen your suggestion. As I stated in my other question that I dont see something like quantiles in bugs.output structure. I have been stuck at this point for almost 6 months now. I am new  to R. I would really appreciate if you can help me get to the solution.

Comment: @Tomas: I am hoping to get some help on this problem.

Comment: @anamika, I gave you my help (i.e. how to compute the quantiles) in my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the `attach.bugs(bugs.output[[i]]...)` when `i=2` is masking the `attach.bugs(bugs.output[[i]]...)` when `i=1`.  The `overwrite=NA` merely prevents deletion, not masking.  Instead of "attach" you could refer directly to `bugs.output[[1]]` or `bugs.output[[2]]` in the call to mean.  The results are stored in `sims.array`; reading the documentation of the bugs function return value in the R2WinBUGS manual should get you the rest of the way there.

I am not sure why you are making the two different bugs calls, each with two chains.  Perhaps you could clarify your purpose?  What I would have done is just run bugs once, specifying the number of chains, which in your case would seem to be four [`(i in 1:2)` x `n.chains=2`] and then print the result.

Comment: My ultimate purpose is to be able to calculate coverage. I am making two different bugs calls because I am running the same model with 2 chains for 2 different datasets. I want to do this for say 300 datasets and then calculate coverage (out of 300 times how many times is the true value of p contained within the 95% prediction interval etc). This is the reason I was trying to identify mean or say any other descriptive specific to an output so that in the next loop I could call that.